# Translate the circle on image while zooming in/out the image

Tags: javascript, css

I have one image and had a circle(drawn using css3) in it.

Now when I zoom in/out the image, I want to keep the position of the circle at the same location in the image, so that when image zoom in/out the circle will translate, but I am unable how to calculate the co-ordinates by which I need to translate the circle on image zoom in/out. Any suggestion!!

The image and the circle are the sibling elements in HTML

Comment: How do you zoom the image? Could you show us your code?

Comment: Besides the zoom, here is the best answers you can find to keep an floating element in position on a background image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942014/scale-element-proportional-to-background-cover-with-jquery ... even a CSS only solution at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36097410/2827823

Comment: @Tresdin, I am using css scaling feature

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while but I wrote something that can be used with `<img>` tag and another element with position:absolute;.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setDimentions(first) {
    IW = $('.img_container img').width();
    IH = $('.img_container img').height();
    PW = $('.pointer').outerWidth();
    PH = $('.pointer').outerHeight();
    pointerL = Number($('.pointer').css('left').replace('px', ''));
    pointerT = Number($('.pointer').css('top').replace('px', ''));
    if (first) {
      Lperc = pointerL * 100 / IW;
      Tperc = pointerT * 100 / IH;
      Wperc = PW * 100 / IW;
      Hperc = PH * 100 / IH;
    }
    Lpx = Lperc * IW / 100;
    Tpx = Tperc * IH / 100;
    Wpx = Wperc * IW / 100;
    Hpx = Hperc * IH / 100;
  }
  setDimentions(true);
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    setDimentions();
    $('.pointer').css({
      'width': Wpx,
      'height': Hpx,
      'top': Tpx,
      'left': Lpx
    })
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.img_container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.pointer {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  border: thin solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  top: 16%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img_container">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XXxgr7xg.jpg">
  <div class="pointer">
  </div>
</div>
```