# How to make website responsive on both retina and normal displays?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

The problem is here.I recently coded a landing page for a client and I made it fully responsive. Now he says that when the page loads, all content should be on the screen and there should be no need to scroll to see the lower part and everything should be fit on the screen. I'm not sure if I am wrong or he, but I think this is not possible at all if you want a responsive website then things will go off screen. I share some pictures so you can see what I mean.
I know that my question is not about coding but more about the possibility of what my client is requesting.

He has a macbook pro '15 inch laptop which I think is a Retina display laptop. So I don't really know what to do about this issue.
[image: As You can see the lower menu is cut and you have to scroll to see it.]
**This is what you see on a macbook pro '15 **
However, in other screens you see all the content.
I just want to know if what the client requests is something real and doable or is it impossible?

Comment: I would suggest applying further media queries to cater for your clients screen size, i.e. reducing the size of the video/headers, as well as the top/bottom margins and paddings. You can also can also cleverly show and hide items on a small screen, only revealed through a toggle when requested by the user.

Comment: @vicgoyso Ok I can do this but if he checks it tomorrow on another screen which needs to scroll then there will be the same problem. I want to know if this is logical from a technical viewpoint that I make a responsive design which doesn't need to be scrolled on any size?

Comment: This can be done in so many ways, though there is no magical formula. My best bet is either keep up with the media queries and/or using percent and viewport units. Also, since this question is too broad I also voted to close it as such.

Comment: Just remembered, check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36097410/2827823