# Absolute position of DIVs with a background image

Tags: html, css

I'm planning to position some DIVs on top of a background image but it doesn't seem to work well. The positions of the DIVs changes when the screen size change. Media Query is not the solution. Any help?

HTML

```
<div class="div-bg" style="background-image:url('https://image.ibb.co/f1qio5/insights_indiamap.jpg')">
  <div class="cities Delhi"></div>
  <div class="cities Bangalore"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div-bg {
    height: 85vh;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.cities {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
.cities.Delhi {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 175px;
}
.cities.Bangalore {
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 275px;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ks03qfkv/)**

Comment: .cities  css left position should be percentage.

Comment: That might be a little more complicated than it seems based on how you want it to scale, check this answer (second part has a CSS only version): http://stackoverflow.com/a/36097410/2827823

Comment: It is better to use % instead of px for your position, so it is responsive. and those dot should be `relative` to the img not `absolute`

Answer (score 0):

if you set a fixed width to container

```
.div-bg{ width:700px;}
```

will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

The position of the red dots is not changing, the position of the background image inside of div-bg is what is changing. Inspect that div while resizing and you will see.  One way to keep this from happening would be to   give the div a fixed width and height.  Check out update [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ks03qfkv/2/).

```
width: 500px;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.div-bg{
   width:555px;
}
```

add this CSS to your code.

Answer (score 0):

For the image dimensions, use vmin units, the will adapt gracefully to the viewport dimension.

And set the position of the cities in percentage

```css
.div-bg {
    height: 100vmin;
    width: 100vmin;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.cities {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
.cities.Delhi {
    position: absolute;
    top: 27%;
    left: 30%;
}
.cities.Bangalore {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    left: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-bg" style="background-image:url('https://image.ibb.co/f1qio5/insights_indiamap.jpg')">
  <div class="cities Delhi"></div>
  <div class="cities Bangalore"></div>
</div>
```